# How can i change the wixWindow formfactor from tablet to mobile?

Tags: javascript, velo

I am currently working on making a website using wix. my problem is that whenever i try to open the website from a tablet, the desktop version is displayed rather than the mobile version.
Is there any way to switch using code?

I tried to edit the wixWindow.formFactor but it showed that its a getter and therefore cannot be edited

I also tried to use string manipulation which didnt seem to help either.

this is the code i tried

```
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';
$w.onReady(function () {
    if (wixWindow.formFactor === "Tablet") {
        wixWindow.formFactor.replace("Tablet", "Mobile");
        //wixWindow.formFactor= "Mobile";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example for code which checks whether you are on mobile , and show button.

also here is documentation for it  [wix corvid](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-tutorial-displaying-elements-in-mobile-only)

```
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

if(wixWindow.formFactor === "Mobile"){
  $w("#button8").show();
}
```